# Crontab que muestre la fecha por terminal

Tags: linux, crontab

Estoy intentando crear un crontab que te muestre la fecha por terminal en un print cada minuto, y no me funciona.Este es el crontab que he hecho yo:

```
* * * * * /home/user1/date.sh
```

Dentro de ese sh hay estas lineas:

```
#!/bin/bash
date
```

Comment: ¿y en que terminal se supone que quieres que se muestre?  Lo digo porque puedes tener tropocientos terminales abiertos a la vez, y aunque lances el cron desde uno en concreto teoricamente el cron se ejecuta en segundo plano, a menos que redirijas la salida a un tty concreto.  Vete al terminal que quieres ver ese cron, escribe `tty` y lo que te salga (por ejemplo `/dev/pts/3`) lo pones en el cron así: `* * * * * /home/user1/date.sh > /dev/pts/3`

Comment: Muchas gracias,funcionó!

Comment: He agregado una respuesta para que la pregunta no quede pendiente de respuesta eternamente. Si te ha funcionado sírvete aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como he dicho en los comentarios, el cron se ejecuta en segundo plano, y no está vinculado al terminal desde el cual lo ejecutes.

Pero puedes ir al terminal que quieres ver ese cron, escribir `tty` y lo que te salga (por ejemplo `/dev/pts/3`) lo pones en el cron así:

```
* * * * * /home/user1/date.sh > /dev/pts/3
```